# How to get supported pixel format of video capture device (camera) in mac os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, avfoundation, objective-c++

Just now i start a small work related to video capture I want all supported pixel formats by a video capture device using avfoundation. I am using CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubtype function to get pixel format in mac(CMPixelFormatType). But i am always getting a value which is not matching from any of the available pixel format (predefined pixel fromat like: kCMPixelFormat_422YpCbCr8_yuvs). Is there any other function present for that purpose.. I searched but till now not found. Returned value is always 1684890161 as pixel format type.

Actual thing I want to ask is :

How can I have all supported pixel formats by a video capture device in Mac. Remember I am not asking for codec type. Its pixel format I need. Please help.. if possible.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: When you translate `1684890161` into `OSType` you will get the four character code `'dmb1'` which seems to be a Matrox specific hardware compression type like motion jpeg.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Its working post it as a answer with some more explanation so that it can be helpful for others also. :) and one more thing is why it is not given in predefined list of formats..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all supported pixel formats, you need to call `CMIOObjectGetPropertyData` with the second parameter `CMIOObjectPropertyAddress` as follows:

```
CMIOObjectPropertyAddress theAddress;
theAddress.mSelector = kCMIOStreamPropertyFormatDescriptions;
theAddress.mScope    = kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
theAddress.mElement  = 0;
```

This will give you a `CFArray` of `CMFormatDescriptionRef`.
Then you iterate over this array and call:

```
CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(yourCMFormatDescriptionRef);
```

Your `CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType` translates into a FourCharacterCode (OSType) of `'dmb1'` which seems to be a Matrox specific hardware compression type.

The reason, you won't find your format in the `CMPixelFormatType` enum is because there are only the most common formats there, which yours is not. The most common on the Mac are `kCMPixelFormat_422YpCbCr8` and `kCMPixelFormat_422YpCbCr10`, both are raw 8 and 10 bit YUV video.